# FactoryGirl gives wrong value on enum status field

Tags: factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am trying to build a FactoryGirl factory for the Client.rb model:

Client.rb

```
  enum status: [ :unregistered, :registered ]

 has_many :quotation_requests

  #Validations

  validates :first_name, 
            presence: true,
            length: {minimum: 2}

  validates :last_name, 
            presence: true,
            length: {minimum: 2}

  validates :email, email: true

  validates :status, presence: true
```

Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :client do
    first_name "Peter"
    last_name "Johnson"
    sequence(:email) { |n| "peterjohnson#{n}@example.com" }
    password "somepassword"
    status "unregistered"
  end
end
```

client_spec.rb

```
    require 'rails_helper'

    RSpec.describe Client, type: :model do

        describe 'factory' do

          it "has a valid factory" do
            expect(FactoryGirl.build(:client).to be_valid
          end

        end
end
```

I get the following errorL

```
  1) Client factory has a valid factory
     Failure/Error: expect(FactoryGirl.build(:client, status: 'unregistered')).to be_valid
       expected #<Client id: nil, email: "peterjohnson1@example.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$urndfdXNfKVqYB5t3kERZ.c.DUitIVXEZ6f19FNYZ2C...", first_name: "Peter", last_name: "Johnson", status: "0", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> to be valid, but got errors: Status can't be blank
```

The error is that Status can't be blank.

I don't understand how this is possible as the factory is clearly assigning a value to the status attribute.

How can I get this factory to build a valid client object?

Rails 4.2
Using factory_girl 4.7.0
Using factory_girl_rails 4.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was caused by the data type I used for the status attribute. I chose string instead of integer.

I solved the problem by running a new migration to change the data type of the status  to integer.

```
class ChangeColumnTypeClientStatus < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :clients, :status,  :integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you forgot the

```
let(:client) { FactoryGirl.create(:client) }
```

on your client_spec.rb

Where're you creating the client object?

Other issue may be that you assign on Factory:

```
status "unregistered"
```

instead of:

> status :unregistered

as a symbol or due to is an enum maybe you should make

> status 0 # :unregistered

Comment: I changed the code to use let(:client) and that did not change anything.  I am not creating a client but am building one to test that the factory builds a client that is valid.  That way I can use the factory for the other tests accurately.  I have tried status :unregistered and status 0 #:unregistered and even though I see the status with an assignment it still gives the error message that 'Status can't be blank'